# How to detect if Google Play is installed? (Not Market)

Tags: android, google-play

Whether the app installed is called Google Play or Market, the package name is the same `com.android.vending`.

I need to be able to detect whether the app is Google Play or Market, I've checked in PackageInfo and nothing except `versionCode` and `versionName` can be of help.

Does anyone know what the first `versionCode` was or `versionName` was for Google Play app?

If anyone knows any other way of detecting this let me know.

Comment: I think you're looking for [getApplicationLabel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)).

Comment: http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en-CA&answer=113410

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/check-if-correct-google-play-service.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured out the answer: `packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to check the application label. I was using the debugger to see what all was being returned in `packageInfo` that's why I didn't see it initially.

```
public static boolean isGooglePlayInstalled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try
    {
           PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           String label = (String) info.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm);
           app_installed = (label != null && !label.equals("Market"));
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
           app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the equivalent for `isAmazonMarketplaceInstalled` would be? Or what the value of `label` would be in the Amazon context?

Comment: Sorry, don't have a kindle, but if you can figure out the apps package name, that's all you really need. It's going to be `com.amazon.<something>` most likely. I would write a quick test to print out all packages that match `com.amazon.*` and see what the package of the app is.

Comment: Okay the package name is most likely `com.amazon.venezia`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this much simplified solution:

```
public boolean isGooglePlayAvailable() {
        boolean googlePlayStoreInstalled;
        int val= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(LocationActivity.this);
        googlePlayStoreInstalled = val == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
        return googlePlayStoreInstalled;
    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This checks for the Google Play SERVICES and not the Google Play Store "app" to launch market targeted intents.

Answer (score 2):

In my App I check possibility to open play store before fire it like:

```
    public static boolean isResolveActivity(Intent intent) {
            return App.getInstance().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER) != null;
        }

   public void isResolveActivity(String appPackage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackage));

      if(isResolveActivity(intent)){
      ...open intent
      }
  }
```

Comment: Best answer for me I guess. `com.android.vending` was `com.google.store` before and the other answer depends on a library ... when I only want to know if showing the link makes sense, "trying it out" as in your answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple piece of code, its easy and to the point with a consideration for not re-inventing the wheel using `GooglePlayServicesUtil`:

```
public static boolean isPlayStoreInstalled(Context context){
try {
    context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_PACKAGE, 0);
    return true;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

This will require you to add this to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION]'
```

Latest `play-services` version is now: `10.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better example as it allows for status' where the user can do something about it i.e re-auth or update. Based on the code in the [GCM client example project](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html):

```
 public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activity.finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This checks for the Google Play SERVICES and not the Google Play Store "app" to launch market targeted intents.